# Dapper .NET: problems with struct parameterized queries

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying to use structs as parameters in [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) queries. It does not work for me. But it seems like [it should work](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/199).

A failing example:

```
struct Simple { public int ID; }

[TestMethod]
public void StructParameter()
{
    int result = Db.Query<int>("select [ID] = @ID", new Simple { ID = 123 }).First();
    result.Should().Be(123);
}
```

A working example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AnonymousParameter()
{
    int result = Db.Query<int>("select [ID] = @ID", new { ID = 123 }).First();
    result.Should().Be(123);
}
```

The error thrown in the first case:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@ID".
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryImpl>d__11`1.MoveNext() in d:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 1553
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in d:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 1443
   ...
```

I am using Dapper version 1.38.

---

Per suggestion by Dirk, property instead of a filed works just fine:

```
struct Simple {
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change the struct field into a property? The changes in the github link you posted basically only change the IL code to use `call` instead of `callvirt` in case of value types. But they still call the `GetGetMethod` to access a property.

Comment: @Dirk:Yes, a property works. Thank you!

Comment: @discrete You should put that edit into an answer & mark it as resolved so that other users can easily find the fix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not caused by using structs, it's caused by using fields instead of properties.

If you'd change `struct Simple` into `class Simple` is still wouldn't work because the parameter reader creates only IL code to read properties.

Changing the `ID` field into a property will solve it.

Comment: I had a spike to fix it to work with both fields and properties, but something was very very wrong in it, and I haven't had chance to debug it (or more likely: redo it) yet; you are entirely correct.